# I can't read content in file ~/.android/debug.keystore ,Should i use editor to read this file?

Tags: android, macos

I can't read content in file ~/.android/debug.keystore ,Should i use editor to read this file?

Some information in this file like this....

> Q.s˛°8å»∆É‹∆⁄ñ;3µ|ì·ù!ú“<˙ˆƒÎ¶á§\õÖ9FË∏VDM9œ”˘Qˆªì ⁄cﬁ|fÿP 0pYtÁGàµÒl íj◊G^¸ß&’5˙⁄Û‚"”#)õòÚ¨u¶
>   &Â¯ÓTÖª€ƒ+‹kÖp#†… aP{ﬂ´b≠Ü&<ªÁ¨bíºË]B}WNÍ÷°5â:E
>   Ké*±áãåﬁ%Ó˛«üÄÙ—‰¡ÃözÅ¡´ÿÏÿØN,≥ﬂ2ú∏
>   é√íçÈn’π,…∆iÈÌŸ∆c="Ù4Ç¯{ÿi/hŸè¢aˆŒ-∞Û¨∞∑‡‰Äã˚ØcÈ'˚ìä*è…U4ﬂ¿r:\®≥∆›Õù™FıDP;a}πÿÌÓˇ£$ØΩÈƒW®d¸ÑH¸∫Æ™ ñeQ‚§F p-æúı‡4Rs%J‚&G2«v‹ .¡+EdÈç@ÿéë}ÛH˙mù>7{)|œkN=í÷Qò°Ç\1¡çÏô;}k5g≤÷Ù¥‡L\Ü
>   ÔÔépgÎYÛ(÷∏  ¥πK∆…U˜á÷@ÃlU+%®aΩYΩõW‡rÓ∏zUC5Z´z)≠-Z(÷ﬂyMø*¯x/Ä~˘!©+Ø5,CŒ¡.¨fçñsøç“w“Æx¥7◊çJdFπBIG¢X‹ƒ4w<≈dØ>àºvﬂ¡OåPÌØW˙PìÎ‡∫í3|9{_5´2¢>áΩ˙{yœ®h
>   *äªƒ∞[“˝s4G]-TEx∂dmﬂ¶6K≠êÔÍiFGs˘\®õ…Oä¸ÌıEîVa$rçÉÄû®◊≥´•J¶§]€tth±ΩmOÈ˚n®q€«»"˛:åÓw,âòÒîF‡L∂Ú∑±≤{ÖÊ8RE¶…QÇÕësùMB±.≤ÀË◊X)Õèü}∫Î∞«’¢d`n±∂∂¢
>   MıÍxx√±qk˝"¿¡3…˘uææ®iâ—⁄}è8Ω§\µ∏®Ú$O“¥ﬂèplÙ<&ÿ:∏ÇÉ[[r˜Ìd„‹´CbÚ v~•‰Ë˜¡s·`pyÓ‘ıFY¬e6ˆmﬂŒLˇ˚è‡´79S^N´±êFdÈ◊·(éîx±:ò}KJ?†rìÃÄƒÛﬂgîBUê>J4©KámBAÊnÆ@≠y" ∞ÃA4!Ò–Œ÷˛à≠y31≈Ü˚–f$ „7|\OVO ’
>   ∑%6vß¡J˚=
>   5â√dÌúcÅ‹QI•±·M°ãÿˇïÔ»˛üﬂ…õX\rjúrRôõ≤g§˙+ñüëÓ–ú∆Ã∂?™YóuØkN”EZ™Ì‰,dÍ’&∑¥˚“#™_Å"Ró70π7Â≤ÕÇÒ(K$ÚÜ)ôëáà∂ºôrmRÔ
>   ótè˘ßÎå-s∆¿fΩ9ñCâ °±$üÛ[≥ù˙óLµÿKÛÆ1Îq«JÛŒü ¥¢Ô⁄kºﬁ≥8
>   ß}Ω`DÕ˜c6úM“6xù≥x√˘Ö"√päè<Ö™Ù™’‡ )”2l`ã{G»ã¿f¿\~t?
>   \æéíXn¬ˆ"&≥@ø‰Wú)!∏\Eóêv”/M\6›?W9ÿ;=’Ov$|jßjfö˚¯ÌX.5090Ç
>   0Çı†eƒ{é0     *ÜHÜ˜

Answer (score 0):

> Should i use editor to read this file?

No. Use **`keytool`** from your Java SDK to work with Java keystore files.